# Compute pandas DataFrame column for value between current row and a future row matching criteria

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a DateIndex of rows. I want to define some logic to create a new column which looks ahead to the next row meeting some criteria, then computes a value of the difference between a column on that future row and the current row.

For example. With the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'measurement': [101, 322, 313, 454, 511, 234, 122, 134, 222, 321, 221, 432],
                    'action': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1]})
```

I'd like to add a row to each column, say, `distance_to_action` which is made up of the difference between the current `measurement` value and the future `measurement` value where `action` is not equal to 0.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.merge_asof` to bring the closest future measurement to a new column, then perform the subtraction.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.merge_asof(df, 
                   df.loc[df.action != 0, ['measurement']], 
                   left_index=True, 
                   right_index=True, 
                   direction='forward',
                   allow_exact_matches=False,  # True if you want same row matches
                   suffixes=['', '_future'])

df['distance_to_action'] = df.measurement - df.measurement_future
```

Output:

```
    measurement  action  measurement_future  distance_to_action
0           101       0               313.0              -212.0
1           322       0               313.0                 9.0
2           313       1               234.0                79.0
3           454       0               234.0               220.0
4           511       0               234.0               277.0
5           234      -1               134.0               100.0
6           122       0               134.0               -12.0
7           134       1               432.0              -298.0
8           222       0               432.0              -210.0
9           321       0               432.0              -111.0
10          221       0               432.0              -211.0
11          432      -1                 NaN                 NaN
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you :)